# "a thrilling wind blew off the frozen lake" What does this expression mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"a thrilling wind blew off the frozen lake"

It's hard to understand the meaning of the sentence above.

1. a thrilling wind means ? Does this mean the wind is very cold ?
2. blow off the frozen lake ? Does this mean the wind broke the frozen lake and the lake's ice is broken ?

Comment: The word [thrilling](https://www.lexico.com/definition/thrilling) means "Causing excitement and pleasure; exhilarating." On its own it doesn't suggest coldness. If a thrilling wind blew off the Sahara desert it would be warm.

Comment: [The meaning of **off** is simply its dictionary one:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off) "from a place or position"

Comment: Are you sure it is not a _chilling_ wind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Most likely "thrilling wind" refers to a wind that is affecting someone.  It was very bracing or causing one to shiver.
2. The wind is coming across the lake and onto the shore.  The breaking of ice is not implied.